# Incrementing different variables on different conditions

Tags: java

I have multiple int type variables and on specific condition any one of those variables got incremented. Now I have to know some data structure in java that i can do this thing without using multiple variables.
A portion of my code is here:

```
switch(diff)
    {
        case 4:
        {
            count4++;
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            count5++;
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            count6++;
            break;
        }
   }
```

Conditions may be increased so it is not good approach to add variable for each new condition. Kindly let me know some other better approach or data structure which can solve my problem.

**Edit 1:**
I am extracting time difference between consucetive lines in log file. Actually in the end I need a summary like 
Difference 3 sec = 10
Difference 4 sec = 5
For above purpose I am using counter variables for each time difference. I need to know about some other way to do this thing,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You might use an array of the accordant data type. Instead of using `count1` it would be `arr[0]` or somethink like this.

Comment: Can the switch case be removed altogether?? In that case There are several work arounds.

Comment: You could for example use Map data structure. Maps have keys and values. Your keys could be your data names and your values integers you increment. If the key doesn't exist you have to add it otherwise you increment the existing

Comment: this sounds like a question for Code Review though. (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange because of the names you gave to your variables, but you could use an array:

```
int[] counts = {0, 0, 0};
```

Then `count4` is `counts[0]`, `count5` is `counts[1]` and `count6` is `counts[2]` so you can do:

```
counts[diff - 4]++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Map (e.g. HashMap) with the key representing the name of the variable and the map's value representing the variable's value. This allows for having a flexible data structure where it is not necessary to know in before how many "variables" there will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap

Example:

```
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("counter5", 1);
    map.put("counter4", 1);
    map.put("counter2", 1);
    map.put("counter1", 1);

    int diff = 2;
    compute(map, diff);
    diff = 2;
    compute(map, diff);
    diff = 1;
    compute(map, diff);
 }

 private static void compute(HashMap<String, Integer> map, int diff)
 {
    System.out.println("Before counter no: "+diff+" value "+map.get("counter" + diff));
    Integer counter = map.get("counter" + diff);
    map.put("counter" + diff, --counter);
    System.out.println("After counter no: "+diff+" value "+map.get("counter" + diff));
    System.out.println("");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pzaenger you can do something like:
As you already know how many case are there so you can initialize an array with that much size. Like you have 10 case then you can initialize an int array of size 10 as:

```
int[] count = new int[10];
```

now suppose you have a case of 4, i.e. 4th index of int array but as index start from 0 so you can do

```
int[4-1] = int[4-1]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to keep track of the diff number you could do something like this.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> pathMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

public void testSaveEntries() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int value = i % 5;
        increaseCounter(value);
    }
}

private void increaseCounter(int i) {
    Integer value = pathMap.get(i);
    pathMap.put(i, value == null ? 1 : ++value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] aaa=new int[]{10,2,4,5,7,8,3,34,4,4,545,5,3,4,4,5,5,5,10,3,4,45,6,2,7};
        Map<Integer, Integer> all_counts=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        for (int key : aaa) {
            if(all_counts.containsKey(key))
            {
                Integer count=all_counts.get(key);
                count++;
                all_counts.put(key, count);

            }
            else
            {
                all_counts.put(key, 1);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : all_counts.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "-->" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `switch`?

Comment: Just as reference, there's also no need for a `Linked`HashMap either I think, and you should use `Entry` if you want to iterate over a `Map`.

Comment: Yes @Djon you can use Entry to iterate over a map...I am editing that one also...:)